# Convert MATLAB use of Probability Density Function (PDF) to Python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

I'm working to convert below MATLAB code to Python:

**MATLAB:**

```
data                        = [ 44374 44034 44150 44142 44332 43986 44423 44346 44199 44129 44173 43981 44152 43797 44167 43944 44069 44327 44083 44473 44530 44361 44067 44154 44212 44537 44158 44428 43911 44397];
RMS                         = sqrt( data );
MA                          = movmean( RMS , 15 );
x                           = RMS - MA;
y                           = linspace( -10 , 10 , 21 );
f_x                         = pdf( x , y );
```

So far I have this **Python** code:

```
from decimal import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

data = [44374, 44034, 44150, 44142, 44332, 43986, 44423, 44346, 44199, 44129, 44173, 43981, 44152, 43797, 44167, 43944, 44069, 44327, 44083, 44473, 44530, 44361, 44067, 44154, 44212, 44537, 44158, 44428, 43911, 44397]
getcontext().prec = 18  # Change the precision
RMS = [Decimal(x).sqrt() for x in data]
RMS = [float(x) for x in RMS]
RMS = np.array(RMS)
MA = movmean(RMS, 15)
x = np.subtract(RMS, MA)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 21)
kde = gaussian_kde(x)
f_x = kde.pdf(y)
```

I have implemented the `movmean` function to be the same as `MATLAB`. Comparing both code I have ensure that `x` values and `y` values are the same for both `MATLAB` and `Python`.

Unfortunately the results after running the `pdf` [Probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) are not equal...

**Results in MATLAB:**

> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 0.800000000000000,
> 0.133333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

**Results in Python:**

> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0000005849, 0.1135087105, 0.6936653409,
> 0.0836530196, 0.0000000072, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

I tried various combinations of `bw_method`s in `gaussian_kde` function without luck.

**Edit:**

Per request in the comment here is my `movmean` function for Python code:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

def movmean_edge_cases(arr, window_size):   
    # adding NaN for edges
    padding = (window_size - 1) // 2
    arr = np.pad(arr, (padding, padding), 'constant')
    # convert zeros to NaN
    arr[arr == 0] = np.nan
    sliding_windows = sliding_window_view(arr, window_shape=window_size)
    left_edge = np.nanmean(sliding_windows[:padding], axis=1)
    right_edge = np.nanmean(sliding_windows[-padding:], axis=1)
    return left_edge, right_edge


def movmean(arr, window_size):
    # Create a windowed filter with equal weights
    weights = np.ones(window_size) / window_size

    # Compute the convolution between the signal and the filter
    mean_values = np.convolve(arr, weights, mode='valid')
    # Compute the edge values
    left_edge, right_edge = movmean_edge_cases(arr, window_size)
    # add edge values to the original list
    mean_values = np.insert(mean_values, 0, left_edge)
    mean_values = np.append(mean_values, right_edge)
    return mean_values
```

Comment: What is `movmean`?

Comment: Don't expect us to guess what those  numbers mean

Comment: @Corralien `movmean` is MATLAB function, see: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html

Comment: @hpaulj I don't know either, this is part of the issue :-(

Comment: @DavidDr90. I know what is `movmean` in Matlab, but what is `movmean` in Python?

Comment: @Corralien I implement a private function to calculate the same exact output as MATLAB, I will add it to the question...